# Validate that a part of a dataframe is groupwise identical to a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe *data*

```
vp | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4
 0 |  a |  b |  c | ...
 0 |  d |  e |  f | ...
 0 |  g |  h |  i | ...
 1 |  a |  b |  c | ...
 1 |  d |  e |  f | ...
 1 |  g |  h |  i | ...
 ...
```

I want to validate that for each *vp* I have the necessary combinations of var1, var2 and var3.

For this I created a dataframe *prototype* holding the necessary combinations

```
 var1 | var2 | var3 
  a   |  b   |  c   
  d   |  e   |  f   
  g   |  h   |  i
```

and attempted to check, that it is identical to the respective part of each vp group

```
data %>% group_by(vp) %>% summarise(identical = identical(. %>% 
                                                            # as.data.frame() %>%
                                                            select(var1, var2, var3) %>%
                                                            arrange(var1, var2, var3),
                                                          prototype %>% arrange(var1, var2, var3))
```

So I expected, that I could select the area of the data.frame per group (maybe transform it into a new data.frame, if the data format would be relevant) and than check, that it is identical.
However the result is always `FALSE`

If I don't do it with the `group_by` and `summarise` but instead using filter(vp == ...) and do it manually per group, it works as expected.

Why am I wrong? And how to achieve my attempt (preferably with dplyr/tidyr style)?

MVC:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(vp = c(rep(0,3), rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
                   v1 = rep(c("a", "d", "g"), 3),
                   v2 = rep(c("b", "e", "h"), 3),
                   v3 = c(rep(c("c", "f", "i"), 2), c("c", "f", "x")))

prototype <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "d", "g"),
                        v2 = c("b", "e", "h"),
                        v3 = c("c", "f", "i"))

expected_result <- data.frame(vp=c(1,2,3), identical=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))

data %>% group_by(vp) %>% summarise(identical = identical(. %>%
                                                            select(v1, v2, v3) %>%
                                                            arrange(v1, v2, v3),
                                                          prototype %>%
                                                            arrange(v1, v2, v3)))
```

Comment: Can you create a real reproducible example, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do a map approach by first splitting the data into groups and them compare it against your prototype:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  group_split(vp) %>%
  map(.x = .,
      .f = ~.x %>%
        select(v1:v3) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        identical(., prototype))
```

The result is a list with TRUE/FALSE. But this can of course easily be turned into another data structure if needed.

```
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

---

Update based on Allan Cameron‘s suggestion:

```
data %>%
  nest(-vp) %>%
  mutate(identical = map(.x = data,
                         .f = ~.x %>%
                           select(v1:v3) %>%
                           as.data.frame() %>%
                           identical(., prototype)) %>%
                       unlist())
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     vp data             identical
  <dbl> <list>           <lgl>    
1     0 <tibble [3 x 4]> TRUE     
2     1 <tibble [3 x 4]> TRUE     
3     2 <tibble [3 x 4]> FALSE
```

Comment: Or `nest(data = -vp)` and `mutate(identical = map(data, ...))` to keep it all in a tibble

Answer (score 3):

I also found another solution:

```
x <- data %>% select(-vx) %>%
  group_by(vp) %>%
  # summarise(id = identical(as.data.frame(cur_data()), prototype))        # deprecated dplyr
  summarise(id = identical(as.data.frame(pick(everything())), prototype))  # new style
x
## A tibble: 3 × 2
#     vp id   
#  <dbl> <lgl>
#1     0 TRUE 
#2     1 TRUE 
#3     2 FALSE
```

I just assumed the wrong data within `.` - and using cur_data() was the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `summarise` along with `toString` like below

```
data %>%
    summarise(
        identical = rowMeans(
            across(v1:v3, toString) == lapply(prototype, toString)) == 1,
        .by = vp
    )
```

which gives

```
  vp identical
1  0      TRUE
2  1      TRUE
3  2     FALSE
```

Comment: This result, however, is not correct, since we‘d expect TRUE for the first two groups.

Comment: @deschen aha, thanks for correcting me. I had a typo `>1`, which is supposed to be `==1`. now it is fixed.